# Enable KeepAlive in apache for specific requests only

Tags: apache, webserver, keep-alive

Is there a way in apache to enable `KeepAlive` for some specific requests only, for example, when the request is for a specific document or from a specific set of ip-addresses.

I have a case where enabling KeepAlive for all the requests will be bad. However, there are some IPs that will do a specific request again and again (several times a second) and turning on KeepAlive will be a good thing here.

Comment: What is the case where keep-alive will be bad?

Comment: well, most of the requests are from end users, the response of which is some url that then fetches content from other servers. I don't think enabling keep alive here is a good option as the users won't have to come back to our server for anything.

Answer (score 0):

You can turn off keep-alives on individual requests by setting the magical environment variable `nokeepalive` using a `BrowserMatch` or `SetEnvIf` directive. For example:

```
SetEnvIf Remote_Addr "^10\.0\.0\." nokeepalive
```

will disable keep-alives for clients from an ip address beginning with 10.0.0.